# jQuery and CSS float issues with Demo

Tags: jquery, css, css-float

I have a jQuery CSS float issue on the sidebar on the following page. The containing DIV does not expand when the content internal does. Thus we cannot determine the size of the DIV for use in another script.

On the following page, you will see a white line at the bottom of the sidebar. Click on option in the form in the centre and you will see the sidebar content expand. The whiteline however does not move.

http://www.divethegap.com/update/configure/adventure-training?qualification=Beginner&level=1

I've tried all combinations of `display:block`, `overflow:visible` and `clear:both` that I can think of and cannot get it working.

Any ideas?

Marvellous

[image: picture showing the white line that shows the bottom of the div is not moving when the content changes]

Comment: It works for me if I remove the `height` from the `sidebar1` `DIV` using Chrome's developer tools.

Comment: Just tried in chrome still not working. Are sure you are looking at the white line on the right

Comment: Yes, did you remove the height using developer tools?

Comment: please try not to use tables in your layout! you're defeating the purpose of using CSS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `#sidebar1` has an explicit `height` set on it.

If you remove this explicit height, the "white line" (border) goes where you expect.

It's being set **with JavaScript** - you should find where in your scripts this `height` is being set, and get rid of it.

Alternatively, a dirty fix would be to run this:

```
$('#sidebar1').css('height', '');
```

to remove the explicit height, before you run the script you describe in this sentence:

> Thus we cannot determine the size of
>   the DIV for use in another script.

Comment: Correct but I had to use the so called 'dirty fix'. Can't find anywhere where it might be.

Comment: I would have looked for the actual line, but there's a little too much JavaScript on there for me to be willing to do so. Also, that site seems very slow to load, you should see if you can improve the load time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your div id `sidebar1` has a hard-coded height.  The white line is the bottom border of that div- your content is overflowing the div and remaining visible without expanding it's container.

Remove that hard-coded height and all should be well in the world again.  Very nice design, btw.

Comment: I'd like to agree with you but it has no fixed height.(unless I have missed something. The CSS gives it a width but no height. It does not want to expand to fit its content not sure why.

Comment: I can't speak to your code, but if you inspect the rendered page the element has a fixed height which looks to be directly applied to the element: <div id="sidebar1" class="sidebar sticky-processed sticky-inactive" style="border-bottom-width: 2px; border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); height: 449px; ">

Next to check is whether you have JQuery setting that height somewhere in the page load.

Comment: I've used the dirty fix above. Thanks for your help and comments on the design